# Trying to change a value in a .env file

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a script that fetches the build number from a `.env` file, adds 1 to it and saves it back to that file. I currently have the code below, but I don't know how to save it back to the file. Any help?

```
$env = file_get_contents('../app/config/.env');

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

if (strpos($env,'build(') !== false) {
    $parsed = get_string_between($env, "build(", ")");
    $parsed = $parsed++;
}
```

My `.env` file looks like this:

```
VERSION_NUMBER="v.1.0 build(32)"
ENVIRONMENT="alpha"
```

Comment: You'll want to recreate the string `$env` and then use `file_put_contents()` to write back to the file. You have a `get_string_between()` function, so why not make the `get_string_before()` and `get_string_after()` functions, and `$env = get_string_before(...) + $parsed + get_string_after(...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I could just do `explode()` and link it all together.

```
$env = file_get_contents('../app/config/.env');

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

if (strpos($env,'build(') !== false) {
    $parsed = get_string_between($env, "build(", ")");
    $data = explode($parsed, $env);

    $parsed = intval($parsed);
    $parsed++;
    $result = $data[0].$parsed.$data[1];
    echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$handle = fopen('../app/config/.env', 'w');
$content = "VERSION_NUMBER=\"v.1.0 build($parsed)\" \n ENVIRONMENT=\"alpha\" ";
fwrite($handle, $content);
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$string = 'build(32)';
$pattern = '/build\\(([\\d]{2})\\)/';
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'call', $string);

function call($v)
{
    return 'build('.($v[1]+1).')';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm over complicating things, but your ENV file looks exactly the same as an INI file. Therefor I would write something like this (explanations are in the codes comments):

```
<?php

# File path
$path = "../app/config/";

# ENV extension
$env = ".env";

# Parse ENV as INI file
$arr = parse_ini_file($path.$env);

# Get current version number
$num = preg_match("#\((.*?)\)#i", $arr['VERSION_NUMBER'], $match);

# Add 1 to version number
$match[1]++;

# Replace version number
$arr['VERSION_NUMBER'] = preg_replace("#\((.*?)\)#", "(".$match[1].")", $arr['VERSION_NUMBER']);

# Function that writes back to ENV file
function write_ini_file($assoc_arr, $path, $has_sections=FALSE) { 
    $content = ""; 
    if ($has_sections) { 
        foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
            $content .= "[".$key."]\n"; 
            foreach ($elem as $key2=>$elem2) { 
                if(is_array($elem2)) 
                { 
                    for($i=0;$i<count($elem2);$i++) 
                    { 
                        $content .= $key2."[] = \"".$elem2[$i]."\"\n"; 
                    } 
                } 
                else if($elem2=="") $content .= $key2." = \n"; 
                else $content .= $key2." = \"".$elem2."\"\n"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    else { 
        foreach ($assoc_arr as $key=>$elem) { 
            if(is_array($elem)) 
            { 
                for($i=0;$i<count($elem);$i++) 
                { 
                    $content .= $key."[] = \"".$elem[$i]."\"\n"; 
                } 
            } 
            else if($elem=="") $content .= $key." = \n"; 
            else $content .= $key." = \"".$elem."\"\n"; 
        } 
    } 

    if (!$handle = fopen($path, 'w')) { 
        return false; 
    }

    $success = fwrite($handle, $content);
    fclose($handle); 

    return $success; 
}

# Save data back to ENV file
write_ini_file($arr, $path.$env);

?>
```